# Which versions of gdb and gcc allow watching rvalue references?

Tags: debugging, c++11, gcc, gdb, rvalue-reference

I am using `GDB 7.8.0.20140729-cvs` and `GCC 4.8.2`. Whenever I try to print the value of a variable referenced by an rvalue reference, I get an error from the debugger complaining about an unknown type, forcing me to manually cast the `T &&` to a `T *`.

Are there newer versions of these where this bug is fixed? Ideally I'd prefer not to upgrade `GCC` if I don't have to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there newer versions of these where this bug is fixed?

No.

Upgrading GCC won't help because it is already doing the right thing (emitting DWARF `DW_TAG_rvalue_reference_type` entries).

But GDB's handling of rvalue references is still broken even in the latest Git sources.

The relevant bug is https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14441