# Debugging C++11 rvalue references with gdb

Tags: c++11, gdb, rvalue-reference

I just noticed that I can not debug **rvalue** references with `gdb-7.7.1` properly.

```
void simple(int &&i) {}
```

When I enter this minimalistic function I can not obtain any meaningful information about `i`. It's **type** and **value** are **unknown** to `gdb`.

```
simple(int&&) (i=<unknown type in /tmp/test, CU 0x0, DIE 0xcd78>) at test.cpp:10
(gdb) p i
$2 = <unknown type in /tmp/test, CU 0x0, DIE 0xcd78>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Are there any sensible workarounds? Will upgrading to `gdb-7.10` solve this *issue*?

Comment: Related: [Which versions of gdb and gcc allow watching rvalue references?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28965431/which-versions-of-gdb-and-gcc-allow-watching-rvalue-references)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick that explains a lot, thanks

Comment: A 3+ year old bug. Wow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunatelly this is caused by a **GDB Bug** : *14441 - Need to support DW_TAG_rvalue_reference_type*

This was **fixed in GDB 8.0**.

*Reference:* https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14441

**Workaround**

Until it is fixed the value of `i` in the above example can be obtained by explicit casting like that:

```
(gdb) p *(int*)i 
$3 = 69
```

Comment: In GDB8.0 this has been fixed.